# How to start device adminstrator settings activity android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to programatically redirect to device adminstrators settings activity . I am able to redirect user to security settings using intent flags but i want to redirect to device adminstrators settings.
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To improve on the above answer

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.DeviceAdminSettings"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
adb -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device shell am start -W -S -N -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "com.android.settings/.DeviceAdminSettings"
```

This will directly take you to the device admin app menu screen of your Android device.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i want to do it from my application and not from shell